# Why are these segments parallel?

Tags: geometry

I constructed something with GeoGebra, and I ran into trouble.

How can I prove this. (Actually I just hope this will be true)

[image]

You can also check this construction https://www.geogebra.org/classic/kvcdt7bd

with navigation button below.

$$$$
I am not good at using English, so sorry in case of confusion.

Comment: Please describe the construction in the the body of your question, so that people don't have to visit a separate site to understand what you're asking. ... Also, it would be helpful to know what you've done to answer the question yourself, so that people don't spend time explaining things you already understand, or using techniques beyond your current level.

Comment: By the way: If I'm reading the construction correctly, the desired parallelism seems to follow fairly directly from [Ceva's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ceva%27s_theorem) and a similarity argument. (Indeed, the circle is irrelevant: Ceva guarantees the parallelism whenever $\overline{AE}$ and $\overline{BD}$ meet at a point on median $\overline{CO}$.)

Comment: To just slightly improve @Blue’s comment: Ceva’s Theorem and the converse of the Basic Proportionality Theorem.

Comment: You can exclude circle. Let consider any triangle ABC. Let O is middle of AB. Let P is in CO. Let D is intersection of BP with AC. Let E is intersection of AP with BC. Fact that DE is parallel to AB can be proven using vector representation of all vectors in basis AB, AC. This solution is mainly equivalent to using Ceva's Theorem.